# Top-right margin displaying "Contents" instead of section title

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, margins, documentclass-writing

I have a class `MyReportClass` where I define what has to be displayed in the margins of all pages of my document. In particular I would like the current section to appear in the top-right margin of each page. However, from the table of contents onwards I get "Contents" instead of the section number and title. When the references section is created through the `\bibliography`command, the top-right margin displays "References" and keeps that also in the appendixes that I have at the end of the document.

[image]

Is there something wrong in the commands of my class?

Below a MWE for my case.

```
\documentclass{MyReportClass}

\begin{document}

\reporttitle{My Title}
    \coursecode{1234}
    \coursename{Course Name}
    \instructorname{Instructor Name}
    \reportauthor{Name}{Surname}{1234}
    \frontcoverpic{example-image-b}

    \initialise

    \section{Section 1}
    \newpage\section{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

`\makemarings` command in `MyReportClass`:

```
\newcommand{\makemargins}{
\makenomenclature
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset{1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./logos/logo.pdf}} % Set image at top of the page
\rhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{\textbf{\reporttitle}}
\lfoot{\coursecode}
}
```

`\initialize` command in `MyReportClass`:

```
\newcommand{\initialise}{
    \makemargins
    \makecoverpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
}
```

For reference, below is the entire `MyReportClass`.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{MyReportClass}
\LoadClass[a4paper,12pt]{article} % Class of the document

%--------------------- Packages ------------------------

\RequirePackage[english]{babel} % Langueage of the document
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Special characters
\RequirePackage[section]{placeins} % For format of sections
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} % Letters not included in UTF-8
\RequirePackage{mathtools} % Equations and mathematic symbols
\RequirePackage{siunitx} % Scientific notation
\RequirePackage{float} % Images formatting
\RequirePackage{graphicx} % Insert figures
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage[justification=centering]{caption} % Centred legends
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\RequirePackage{wallpaper}
\RequirePackage{nomencl}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{url}
\RequirePackage[pdfencoding=auto,psdextra,hidelinks]{hyperref} % Legends in sub-figures
\RequirePackage{amsmath,bm,amssymb}
\RequirePackage{amsfonts}
\RequirePackage{bookmark} % Faster updated bookmarks
\RequirePackage{textcomp}

% Package for nice tables
\RequirePackage{booktabs,makecell}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
\sisetup{
    %  output-decimal-marker = {,},
    detect-weight,
    mode = text
}
\newcommand*{\specialcell}[2][b]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand*{\specialcellbold}[2][b]{%
    \bfseries
    \sisetup{text-rm = \bfseries}%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand*{\leftspecialcell}[2][b]{%
    \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}%
}

%Package for labelling matrix rows and columns
\RequirePackage{blkarray}

% Package to adjust labelled matrices
\RequirePackage{makebox,bigstrut,relsize}

% Page configuration
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,hscale=0.75,vscale=0.8}

%Package to modify chapter header
%\RequirePackage{titlesec}
%Color for sections head
\RequirePackage{color}
\definecolor{tdblue}{RGB}{0,174,239}
\RequirePackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\color{tdblue}}
\subsectionfont{\color{tdblue}}
\subsubsectionfont{\color{tdblue}}
\paragraphfont{\color{tdblue}}

%MATLAB command
\RequirePackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\MATLAB}{\textsc{Matlab}\xspace}

%Typesetting a MATLAB code
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{bigfoot} % to allow verbatim in footnote
\RequirePackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\let\ph\mlplaceholder % shorter macro
\lstMakeShortInline"
\lstset{
    style              = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
    escapechar         = ",
    mlshowsectionrules = true,
}

% Per-section figure, equation, table and lstlisting numbering
\RequirePackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}}

% Package for references with numbers
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
\RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
\setcitestyle{numbers}


% Set graphics path
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}

%-------------- Define command for missing figures ------------
\let\StandardIncludeGraphics\includegraphics%
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
    \IfFileExists{./figures/#2}{%
        \StandardIncludeGraphics[#1]{#2}%
    }{%
    \IfFileExists{#2}{%
        \StandardIncludeGraphics[#1]{#2}%
    }{%
    \StandardIncludeGraphics[#1]{example-image-a}}}%
}% End of command

%-------------------- Report information ----------------------

\newcommand{\coursecode}[1]{\renewcommand{\coursecode}{#1}}
\newcommand{\coursename}[1]{\renewcommand{\coursename}{#1}}
\newcommand{\instructorname}[1]{\renewcommand{\instructorname}{#1}}
\newcommand{\reporttitle}[1]{\renewcommand{\reporttitle}{#1}}
\newcommand{\reportauthor}[3]{\renewcommand{\reportauthor}{#1 {\scshape #2} \dots\dots {\bfseries #3}}}
\newcommand{\frontcoverpic}[1]{\renewcommand{\frontcoverpic}{\includegraphics[height=5cm]{#1}}}

\newcommand{\makemargins}{
\makenomenclature
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset{1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{./logos/logo.pdf}} % Set image at top of the page
\rhead{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{\textbf{\reporttitle}}
\lfoot{\coursecode}
}

\newcommand{\makecoverpage}{
\begin{titlepage}

    \centering % Center the content
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{./logos/logo_blue.pdf}\par\vspace{1cm} % Insert logo
    {\scshape\LARGE Delft University of Technology \par} % Name of the university
    \vspace{1cm} % Vertical space of 1.5 cm
    {\scshape\Large \coursename \\ \large \coursecode \\ \normalsize \instructorname \par}
    \vspace{0.5cm} % Vertical space of 1 cm
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[0.4 cm]
    {\huge\bfseries \reporttitle \par} \
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[1 cm]
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \frontcoverpic\\[1.5 cm]
    \normalsize \reportauthor\\
    \vfill
    {\large \today\par} % Visualization of the date

\end{titlepage}
}

\newcommand{\initialise}{
    \makemargins
    \makecoverpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
}

% Define newcommand for norm
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
```

Comment: `\clearpage\pagestyle{fancy}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I have substituted `\pagestyle{fancy}` in the `\makemargins` command with `\clearpage\pagestyle{fancy}`, but nothing changes. Do I need that line somewhere else?

Comment: You have a very messy (sorry!) `.cls` file and and there might be many possibilities that cause your issue. At first glance I cannot detect a starting point other than to debug the `.cls` file.

Comment: What would you have it display instead of 'Contents' - '0 Section 0'?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I agree that my `.cls` is quite messy, sorry for that. Maybe I can try commenting out some parts of it and seeing what changes.

Comment: @Pippip19 yes, precisely that. In the example shown it would be "1 Secion 1"

Comment: I have tried commenting out `\tableofcontents` in the `\initialise` command and now nothing is displayed in the top-right margins. So I guess the problem has to do with the fact that the sections are not recognized by `\leftmark`.

Comment: Just to confirm - You get 'Contents' on all following pages? When I compile it I get 1 Section 1, 2 Section 2. Could it be something to do with your build system? (This caused me to misunderstand the question; I thought you were trying to have '0 Contents' displayed instead of 'Contents'!).

Comment: @Pippip19 I get "Contents" on all following pages, whereas I would like to get "1 Section 1" or "2 Section 2" according to the section of the page. I have tried to cancel all the temporary files (.toc, .log, etc.) and rebuild, but even that does not work.

Comment: Hmm. It is difficult for me to know what to suggest as I cannot recreate the issue. Any obvious warnings in .log? (Searching for 'warning', 'Warning')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89572/discussion-between-pippip19-and-francesco).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging with the OP it I have found that using the 'lower-level' `\rightmark` command (see section 12 of the [fancyhdr docs](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf)) gets things working. If you want to edit exactly how the section names appear, you can edit the `\sectionmark` command (see code).

```
\newcommand{\makemargins}{
\makenomenclature
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyheadoffset{1cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{2cm}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{./logos/logo.pdf}} % Set image at top of the page
% \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ \ ##1}} % Change appearance of marks
\rhead{\nouppercase{\rightmark}} % Use \rightmark instead of \leftmark..
\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{\textbf{\reporttitle}}
\lfoot{\coursecode}
}
```